# Animations in PageView get lost when Pageview is being dragged

Tags: flutter

I have written a [package](https://github.com/Mr-Pepe/stroke-order-animator) to animate Chinese characters. The animation works until I put a character in a PageView and drag and hold the PageView, for example when scrolling very slowly. Suddenly the animation does not get updated anymore. Also listeners to that animation do not get called anymore. The example from the package can be run as is and exposes the behavior.

Any ideas why that behavior can be observed? It seems somehow that the PageView is not wired to the animation anymore while dragged.